# How to split the file path to extract the various subfolders into variables? (Ubuntu Bash)

Tags: bash

I need help with Ubuntu Precise bash script.

I have several tiff files in various folders

```
masterFOlder--masterSub1 --masterSub1-1 --file1.tif
                         |--masterSub1-2 --masterSub1-2-1 --file2.tif 
          | 
          |--masterSub2  --masterSub1-2 .....
```

I need to run an Imagemagick command and save them to new folder "converted" while retaining the sub folder tree i.e. the new tree will be

```
converted --masterSub1 --masterSub1-1 --file1.png
                         |--masterSub1-2 --masterSub1-2-1 --file2.png 
          | 
          |--masterSub2  --masterSub1-2 .....
```

How do i split the filepath into folders, replace the first folder (masterFOlder to converted) and recreate a new file path?

Thanks to everyone reading this.

Comment: How do you execute your imagemagick command?

Answer (score 1):

This script should work.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob && [[ $# -eq 2 && -n $1 && -n $2 ]] || exit

MASTERFOLDER=${1%%+(/)}/
CONVERTFOLDER=$2

OFFSET=${#MASTERFOLDER}

while read -r FILE; do
    CPATH=${FILE:OFFSET}
    CPATH=${CONVERTFOLDER}/${CPATH%.???}.png
    CDIR=${CPATH%/*}
    echo "Converting $FILE to $CPATH."
    [[ -d $CDIR ]] || mkdir -p "$CDIR" && echo convert "$FILE" "$CPATH" || echo "Conversion failed."
done < <(exec find "${MASTERFOLDER}" -mindepth 1 -type f -iname '*.tif')
```

Just replace `echo convert "$FILE" "$CPATH"` with the actual command you use and run `bash script.sh masterfolder convertedfolder`

Comment: My imagemagick command for a single file is convert file1.tif file1.png

Comment: @firaqpasto Then it should be `convert "$FILE" "$CPATH"`. Just remove `echo `.